# get posts by tag Id using Prisma.js

Tags: node.js, orm, prisma, prisma2

How can I get posts by filtering `tagId`?

I test this code but it doesn't work:
I get all of the posts without filtering!

```
prisma.post.findMany({
      include:
      {
        Tags:
        {
          where: { TagId: tagId  },
          include:
          {
            Tag: true
          }
        }
      },
    })
```

**schema.prisma:**

```
model Post {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String
  tags  PostTags[]
}

model PostTags {
  id     Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  post   Post? @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  tag    Tag?  @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id])
  postId Int?
  tagId  Int?
}

model Tag {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String     @unique
  posts PostTags[]
}
```

how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to filter it inside the main query and not in `include`. `include` is only for fetching relations and then filtering inside them, it will not affect the main query.

Your final query would look like:

```
await prisma.post.findMany({ 
  where: { tags: { some: { tag: { id: 1 } } } } 
})
```

You can read more about querying for relations [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#relation-filters).

Comment: What if i want to find posts having two tags or more ?