# How to filter a prisma association to have only 1 association on a 1 to many

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, prisma, prisma2

I have a DB with posts and tags. I want to find posts that only contain 1 tag with a specific tagId and no other tags at all. The code below works, but it requires the server to filter the results manually which will make pagination difficult. Does anyone have a direct query that can do this?

I tried a groupBy on postId in PostTag, but the issue is when I search for the tagId in a where clause then all entries on the PostTag only have 1 entry which makes counting impossible.

I am using Prisma as a wrapper for a PostgresQL DB.

```
        const query = await prisma.post.findMany({
            where: {
                tags: {
                    some: {
                        tagId: Number(tagId),
                    }
                },
            },
            select: {
                id: true,
                tags: {
                    select: {
                        tagId: true,
                    }
                }
            },
        })
        const tagIds = query
            .filter(item => item.tags.length === 1)
            .map(item => ({ id: item.id }));
```

Models

```
model Post {
    id                     Int                         @id @default(autoincrement())
    tags                   PostTag[]
}

//Pivot Table
model PostTag {
    id           Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
    post         Post              @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    postId       Int
    tag          Tag               @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id])
    tag    Id    Int
}

model Factiii {
    id              Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
    tags            PostTag[]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the keyword here is `having` which unfortunately Prisma doesn't yet support in where clauses.

They support `having` in the `groupBy` function, but that doesn't allow you to check based on the count.

You can try this, which feels like a workaround but could work in your case:

```js
const query = await prisma.post.findMany({
            where: {
                tags: {
                    every: { //this is the change
                        tagId: Number(tagId),
                    }
                },
            },
            select: {
                id: true,
                tags: {
                    select: {
                        tagId: true,
                    }
                }
            },
        })
```

The idea here is that since a post can contain a tag only once, if you provide only 1 value for comparison (`Number(tagId)` in this case) it can only match posts with one tag, which is the tag you care about. *if my logic is wrong, please kindly let me know*

Alternatively, you can consider doing a raw query with Prisma where you supply your own SQL code directly.

If you're doing that, BE CAREFUL! Read more about raw queries with Prisma to be safe against SQL injections.

Here is the SQL code you can use for this purpose:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM Post p
JOIN (
  SELECT pt.post_id
  FROM PostTag pt
  JOIN Tag t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
  WHERE t.id = 1 -- Replace with your specific tagId
  GROUP BY pt.post_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) subquery ON p.id = subquery.post_id;
```

Comment: I tried the every method and for some reason it pulls up posts without tags now. They don't even have the tagId I was looking for which is weird.

Comment: Not sure why they behave that way, thanks for the help though. I'm going to see if anyone can solve this in a Prisma way then I'll switch to a direct SQL query.

Comment: Interesting, did you try doing an `AND` in the `every` block there to ensure each post "has a tagId AND has tagId = X` ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this from Rayan answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170874/get-posts-by-tag-id-using-prisma-js)

```
await prisma.post.findMany({
```

where: { tags: { some: { tag: { id: 1 } } } }
})